# XSLT to group the xml elements based on the Key value XSLT1.0

Tags: xslt, biztalk

I will receive a CRM Response XML as below in BizTalk

```
<ns0:RetrieveMultipleResponse xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Metadata" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
<ns0:RetrieveMultipleResult>
    <ns4:Entities>
      <ns4:Entity>
        <b:Attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
            <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>ccx_datevaccineinfostatementpresented</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:dateTime" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">2012-08-14T04:00:00Z</c:value>
          </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>ccx_administeredamount</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:decimal" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">0.75000000</c:value>
          </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>ccx_immunizationid</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:guid" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">826c2b0e-a349-e411-866c-00155d1e1f77</c:value>
          </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
     </b:Attributes>
  </ns4:Entity>
   <ns4:Entity>
        <b:Attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
            <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>ccx_datevaccineinfostatementpresented</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:dateTime" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">2012-08-14T04:00:00Z</c:value>
          </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>ccx_administeredamount</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:decimal" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">0.25000</c:value>
          </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>ccx_immunizationid</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:guid" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">766c2b0e-a349-e411-866c-00155d1e1f77</c:value>
          </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
     </b:Attributes>
  </ns4:Entity>
<ns4:Entity>
        <b:Attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
            <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>ccx_datevaccineinfostatementpresented</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:dateTime" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">2012-08-14T04:00:00Z</c:value>
          </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>ccx_administeredamount</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:decimal" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">0.7500000000</c:value>
          </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <c:key>ccx_immunizationid</c:key>
            <c:value i:type="d:guid" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">826c2b0e-a349-e411-866c-00155d1e1f77</c:value>
          </b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
     </b:Attributes>
  </ns4:Entity>
</Entities>
```

I have  to count the distinct Entities based on ccx_immunizationid value & also I have to group the fields if both entity has same immunization ID. If the xml file (without namespace) and the field is `<ccx_immunizationid>2323</ccx_imunizationid>`, I can use something like below,

```
<xsl:template match="//Entity/Attributes[not(./ccx_immunizationid= preceding::ccx_immunizationid)]">
```

but here, I have to look for the key 'ccx_immunizationid' and its value.

I am using custom xslt in BizTalk map.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by *"group the fields"* - maybe you could add an example of the desired output of your transformation. In any case your current approach may fail if the elements are not in the expected order. You will need to create an xslt key on ccx_immunizationid. Side note: ["The Good, Bad and Ugly of Integrating Dynamics CRM and BizTalk"](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/the-good-bad-and-ugly-of-integrating-dynamics-crm-2011-and-biztalk-server-2010/)

Comment: Do you just have to remove duplicates?  Or do you ever get an instance where the guid is the same but the other values are different?  Check out [Muenchian Grouping in BizTalk](http://blog.tallan.com/2014/12/09/muenchian-grouping-in-biztalk-while-keeping-mapper-functionality/) and the links there for using xsl:keys to group nodes.